# 'SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input'. error on parsing JSON?

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax, syntax-error

I've got this AJAX function:

```
function fetchSocialCount(type,fileSrc){
    var count = null;
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.onload = function(){
        if(req.status === 200 && req.readyState === 4){
            console.log(req.responseText);
            count = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
        }
    }
    req.open("GET","../scripts/php/returnSocialCount.php?type=" + type + "&fileSrc=" + fileSrc,false);
    req.send();
    if(count !== null){
        return count;
    }
    else{
        console.log("The AJAX request has failed.");
    }
}
```

But when I run it, I get a `'SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input'.` error. The Chrome Dev Tools also covers the `count = JSON.parse(req.responseText);` part in blue, so I'm guessing it's something wrong with the JSON I'm recieving. From the PHP script, I'm sending a pretty complex JSON object, so I tried to send a really basic one and it worked without problems.

This is the part of the PHP script that sends the response:

```
echo '{"likes":'.$json->videoListArray[$i]->likes . ',"dislikes":' . $json->videoListArray[$i]->dislikes . '}';
```

Is there something wrong with the syntax of the `echo`? What's the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: You can use the browser developer tools to see what the actual response text looks like.

Comment: @Pointy Thank you. Do you know where might that option be in Chrome?

Comment: press F12 then choose the console tab. then try doing an ajax request again it will appear there.

Comment: I wouldn't advise creating the JSON like that. Create an associative array in normal PHP syntax and then use `echo json_encode($array);` to create the JSON and return it to the ajax call. You run the risk of introducing a syntax error by creating this manually...

Comment: try : echo '{"likes":"'.$json->videoListArray[$i]->likes . '","dislikes":"' . $json->videoListArray[$i]->dislikes . '"}';

Comment: Look in the main "Network" tab. You'll see a GET request with type "xhr". Click on that, and you'll get a panel that gives you more tabs ("Headers", "Preview", "Response", "Timing").  The "Response" tab will show you the raw text returned from the request.

Comment: Please, [RTM](http://php.net/json_encode). PHP has an easy to use `json_encode` and an equally easy to use `json_decode` function so that you don't have to string your own json data together, which is bound to end in tears

Comment: "This request has no response data available." I don't know why. It works with simple JSON. I'll try to use @War10ck 's method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that there is probably a syntax error in your JSON that you're returning. It's not usually a good idea to manually create JSON for this very reason. Try creating an associative array and then use `json_encode()` to return the desired data to the ajax call:

```
// Create the array
$data = array();

// Add the data
$data['likes'] = $json->videoListArray[$i]->likes;
$data['dislikes'] = $json->videoListArray[$i]->dislikes;

// Generate JSON from the array and return the desired results
echo json_encode($data);
```

**Reference Documentation:**

- [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)
- [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know associative arrays encode to JSON objects.

Comment: @aCodingN00b You're welcome. Any array structure in php usually encodes to JSON pretty well, even nested arrays or plan `0` based index arrays. If you ever return JSON to your server, you can also use `json_decode($return_data);` to generate a php object from the returned data that you can use. Alternately, using `json_decode($returned_data, TRUE);` will modify the returned data back into a php associative array, so you have several options. I'll link the PHP doc references in my answer for these two functions.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `json_encode` ([PHP json_encode manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)) and `echo` it like so:

```
echo json_encode(array('likes'=>$json->videoListArray[$i]->likes, 'dislikes'=>$json->videoListArray[$i]->dislikes));
```

My guess is you have a comma, semi-colon, or some other character in your response that is causing the issue. `json_encode` will make sure everything is formatted nicely.

**EDIT** - War10ck beat me to the punch.